# データフレームの一部の列において他のデータフレームの要素と一致するものを特定の番号に置き換える

Tags: python, pandas

以下のデータフレームの一部の列において他のデータフレームの要素と一致するものを特定の番号に置き換える方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names = "A", "B", "C", "D"
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names,
                    'Test1' : [50, "Math", "game", "game"],
                    'Test2' : ["English", 40, 45, "game"],
                    'Test3' : ["work", "movie","Japanese", 50],
                    'Test4' : [30,"work","movie" ,"Japanese"]}
                  )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test' : ["English", "Math", "Japanese"],
                    'TestNumber' : [10, 20, 30]}
                  )    
df1 
df2
```

出力結果
df1

```
   Name Test1   Test2   Test3   Test4
0   A    50    English  work     30
1   B   Math     40     movie   work
2   C   game     45   Japanese  movie
3   D   game    game     50    Japanese
```

df2

```
    Test    TestNumber
0   English    10
1   Math       20
2   Japanese   30
```

という二つのデータフレームがあります。
(df1のイメージとして、4回の実験中1回のみ英語・数学・国語いずれかを勉強し、それ以外の3回の実験では何をして過ごしたのか睡眠をしたらその時間、その他は活動名を記録するというものです。実際はnamesもdf2のTestに相当するものも膨大にあります)
これを、df1のTest1、Test2、Test3、Test4の中でdf2のTestと一致するものだけそのTestNumberで表して最終的に

```
  Name TestNumber   Test
0   A   10         English
1   B   20          Math
2   C   30         Japanese
3   D   30         Japanese
```

となるようにしたいですが、方法が全く思いつきません...。
何か有効な方法はないでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか

> もう少しシンプルに記述できそうですがとりあえず・・。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
names = "A", "B", "C", "D"
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : names,
                    'Test1' : [50, "Math", "game", "game"],
                    'Test2' : ["English", 40, 45, "game"],
                    'Test3' : ["work", "movie","Japanese", 50],
                    'Test4' : [30,"work","movie" ,"Japanese"]}
                  )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test' : ["English", "Math", "Japanese"],
                    'TestNumber' : [10, 20, 30]}
                  )


df1['TestNumber'] = df1.apply(lambda d: d.loc['Test1':].map(df2.set_index('Test').TestNumber).dropna().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)[0]
print(df1)
#   Name Test1    Test2     Test3     Test4  TestNumber
# 0    A    50  English      work        30        10.0
# 1    B  Math       40     movie      work        20.0
# 2    C  game       45  Japanese     movie        30.0
# 3    D  game     game        50  Japanese        30.0


# 必用であればTest1～Test4を削除
print(Df1.drop(['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4'], axis=1))
#   Name  TestNumber
# 0    A        10.0
# 1    B        20.0
# 2    C        30.0
# 3    D        30.0
```

**【追記】**
上記の処理内容をわかりやすく書き直してみました。

```
# df2 より 教科名->数値の変換用のSeriesデータを作成
conv = df2.set_index('Test').TestNumber
# 行毎にループ
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    # Test1以降の列を変換データにて変換
    tmp = row['Test1':].map(conv)
    # 上の処理で変換できなかったデータは削除
    tmp = tmp.dropna()
    # 結果を 'TestNumber'列に追加
    if tmp.size > 0:
        df1.loc[idx, 'TestNumber'] = tmp[0]
print(df1)
```

**【更に追記】**

```
# 上記のループの結果
print(df1)
#   Name Test1    Test2     Test3     Test4  TestNumber
# 0    A    50  English      work        30        10.0
# 1    B  Math       40     movie      work        20.0
# 2    C  game       45  Japanese     movie        30.0
# 3    D  game     game        50  Japanese        30.0

# Test1～4 の列を削除
df1 = df1.drop(['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4'], axis=1)
print(df1)
#   Name  TestNumber
# 0    A        10.0
# 1    B        20.0
# 2    C        30.0
# 3    D        30.0

# df2とマージ
ret = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='TestNumber')
print(ret)
#   Name TestNumber      Test
# 0    A         10   English
# 1    B         20      Math
# 2    C         30  Japanese
# 3    D         30  Japanese
```

**【更に追記２】**
ループ内に教科名を追加する処理を追加

```
conv = df2.set_index('Test').TestNumber
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    # Test1以降の列を変換データにて変換
    tmp = row['Test1':].map(conv)
    # 変換できたデータを'Test'列に追加
    df1.loc[idx, 'Test'] = row[row['Test1':].index[tmp.notnull()][0]]
    # 上の処理で変換できなかったデータは削除
    tmp = tmp.dropna()
    # 結果を 'TestNumber'列に追加
    if tmp.size > 0:
        df1.loc[idx, 'TestNumber'] = tmp[0]
```

Comment: Index値（Column名を含む）にダブりが生じたことによるエラーかと思いますが、
実際のデータを見てみないとどこでエラーが生じたのかが判別つきません。

とりあえず、前回の回答をもうすこし分割して処理内容をわかりやすくしたバージョンを挙げておきましたので、こちらを試してみてください。
これであれば、どこの部分でエラーが出たかを判別しやすいと思います。

Comment: 追記していただいた方法でやってみたら、tmp = row['Test1':].map(conv)の部分で同じエラーが出てきてしまいました。Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4ひとつづつ行う方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: df2の Test列に同じ教科が２つ以上あるということはありませんか？

Comment: 大文字と小文字の違いですが、同じ教科はあります(Mathとmathなど)このデータフレームは写真をスキャンしたものをもとにしているので、スキャンで大文字が小文字と認識されても大丈夫なように作っていました

Comment: いや、大文字・小文字の違いがあれば大丈夫かと思います。
試しに
  "print(df2[df2['Test'].duplicated(keep=False)])"  
とすると何が表示されますか？

Comment: あ、ありました！初歩的なミスで申し訳ありません。ですが、今度はindex out of boundsとエラーが出てしまいました

Comment: df1.loc[idx, 'TestNumber'] = tmp[0]のところです。また、それとは別にKeyErrorで0　(←temp[0]の0だと思います)もでてきました。配列のサイズを間違えているのでしょうか？

Comment: 可能性として、変換が引きあたらない行が存在するということはありませんか？

Comment: とりあえず、回答を変換が引きあたらない場合は 'TestNumber' にデータを書かないようにしてみました。

Comment: 最後の方法でうまくいきました！！ご指摘の通りどの教科も勉強していないイレギュラーなデータがありました。最後までお付き合いくださり本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: またまた失礼いたします。もし最後にTestNumberと一緒に教科名も同時に一覧で表示したい場合は、idexとrowでそれぞれ指定するのでしょうか？

Comment: pandas.merge() を使用するとよいと思います。
ret = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='TestNumber')

Comment: ありがとうございます。これですと、1列ずつしかできないと思うのですが、ループのなかで4列まとめて検索し1列にだす、というやり方はさすがにないですよね…？

Comment: 質問の意図がよくわかりません。前回までの結果としては "Name" と "TestNumber" の２列で構成されており、今回は "TestNumber" の値を基に "Test" 行を追加するだけなので、１回の実行でよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 一応、回答欄に追記しておきました

Comment: 私の書き方が悪く混乱させてしまい申し訳ありません…実は、使用しているデータは例えばMathだけではなくScienceも20というTestNumberがふられているなど、複数の教科名が同じ番号に存在しているのです。

Comment: 大変遅くなりました。回答を追記しました

Comment: お忙しい中、本当にありがとうございます。大変助かりました！